# PostMessage a BM_CLICK to LinkLabel doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

I'm using the following code:

```
PostMessage(handle, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

This works to click a `Button`, but not a `LinkLabel`. Any clue as to why not? And is there a workaround?

(Moving the cursor there and clicking is not suitable unless there's a way to get the LinkLabel's coordinates from its handle only. And I'd rather not do that even then, unless there is no other way. Also, this should be done in the caller's code only, with no changing of the LinkLablel's application code.)

Comment: The workaround depends on what you are trying to do - specifically, what are your requirements and constraints.

Comment: BM_CLICK is a button message; why would you expect it to work on a control that's not a button?

Comment: @EricLaw OK. So what would be the appropriate message for a LinkLabel? (I don't have much experience with WinApi.)

Comment: Probably the pair WM_LBUTTONDOWN / WM_LBUTTONUP

Comment: @EricLaw Those seem to be notifications occurring _after_ a click. If I'm wrong - Please tell me how to use them. (I tried the same as BM_CLICK but nothing happens.)

Comment: Why don't you just use the automation interface instead of trying to fake input?

Comment: @EricLaw Why would you want to fake mouse input?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What do you mean? (From a little searching - it looks like that depends on changing the second application's code. I can't do that.)

Comment: Search harder. Use UIAutomation. It's got its own .net namespace! Do you even know what's behind a `LinkLabel`? Why are you poking at its low level implementation without even knowing what's behind it? Well, don't poke at it at all. Use the automation API as nature intended.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have been searching and trying for a _long_ time and haven't come across it (unless some of the other stuff I've seen is that and not mentioned by name.) but OK. If you suggest that - then thanks, I'm taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be

```
LinkLabel label = (LinkLabel)Control.FromHandle( handle );
((IButtonControl)label).PerformClick();
```

(haven't tested it though)

The trick is to get the reference to the actual link label so that you can use the fact that it implements the `IButtonControl` interface.

**Edit 1**: how about that then:

```
int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
int WM_LBUTTONUP   = 0x202;
int MK_LBUTTON     = 1;

PostMessage( handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, 0 );
PostMessage( handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, 0 );
```

**Edit 2**: this should also work (inspired by suggestion from David Heffernan)

```
AutomationElement    label = AutomationElement.FromHandle( handle );
var invokePattern = label.GetCurrentPattern( InvokePattern.Pattern ) as InvokePattern;
invokePattern.Invoke();
```

Comment: From the way he wrote this, I think he's trying to send the click across processes.

Comment: As EricLaw said - I'm 'clicking' on another process. (And I tried your code. `label` remains `null`.)

Comment: The first doesn't work. (By the way - You have to specifically add the `@ispiro` to notify me. OP's don't get messages from answers.) I'm looking into your second edit now. Thanks.

Comment: @ispiro: I've been using SO for quite some time and I would bet that OPs **do** get notifications from answers. Something new learnt then.

Comment: I've added all the references that seemed to be needed, but Mouse does not include a `Move` method. Nor a `Click` method.

Comment: @ispiro: edited once again, this time I've double checked this works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your perseverance. A pity I cannot upvote this more than once.